# Line continuation not working in VBA for 2D Array construction

Tags: excel, vba, line-continuation

In the following Subroutine, defining a two dimensional array doesn't seem to work with line continuation.  TestArray1 initializes as expected, but when I add line continuation I get the message,

> "Compile Error - Closing bracket missing".

(Actually I'm not sure of the exact wording in English, doing this in German.  In German the error message is,

> "Fehler beim Komilieren: Fehlende schliesende Klammer".

I'm sure the English is not far off.)
Why would this not work?

```
Sub TestArrays()


Dim TestArray1 As Variant, TestArray2 As Variant

TestArray1 = [{"1String1", "1String2", "1String3"; "2String1", "2String2", "2String3"; "3String1", "3String2", "3String3"}]

TestArray2 = [{"1String1", "1String2", "1String3"; _
"2String1", "2String2", "2String3"; _
"3String1", "3String2", "3String3"]}

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854386/how-to-continue-the-code-on-the-next-line-in-vba?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba line continuation with bracket expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175304/vba-line-continuation-with-bracket-expression)

Comment: Though note that you've got the order mixed up at the end `}]`, not `]}`.

Comment: Thanks, these two posts do address the question, however I'm left with the same problem.  So I get that whenever you use square brackets [], Excel takes this as Excel, and not as VBA, so doesn't recognize continuation.  Stringing short strings together in a longer string and then using Evaluate does work, but only for strings less than 255 characters long in totoal.  I was trying to avoid filling a two-dimensional array by using a whole lot of lines of: myArray (1,1) = "Str1", myArray(1,2)  = "Str1 and stuff", etc., or using a loop. Any other ideas before I get down to the grind? ;)

Comment: to BigBen - yes thanks, and it also got the same error when I corrected it.  Must have gotten switched in submission.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use square brackets.

Square brackets in VBA **DO NOT** stand for "this is an array", even though it *looks* like it (if you're any familiar with JSON anyway), and even though it *might* work.

Square brackets in VBA stand for "this is an expression that the host application will be evaluating at run-time".

In other words, it's giving work to Excel's expression evaluation engine: it's not VBA, it's Excel. The syntax of whatever is inside a square-bracketed expression must be legal in Excel's formula bar<sup>1</sup>.

Use the `Array` standard VBA function to create an array in VBA:

```
TestArray1 = Array("1String1", "1String2", "1String3", "2String1", "2String2", "2String3", "3String1", "3String2", "3String3")
```

Split it up with a line continuation at any point between two strings:

```
TestArray1 = Array( _
    "1String1", "1String2", _
    "1String3", "2String1", _
    "2String2", "2String3", _
    "3String1", "3String2", _
    "3String3")
```

Note that the inconsistent `;` vs `,` separators are probably part of the problem: Excel formulas use your system's *list separator* character: that's the character you'll want to use in square-bracket expressions - but you don't need to do that, because you don't need any square-bracket expressions.

There is no syntax for inline-initializing a 2D array in VBA. Declare & size your array explicitly instead:

```
Dim my2D(1 To 10, 1 To 10)
my2D(1, 1) = "1string1"
'...
```

If you have that much hard-coded strings in your code, then you are coding *data*. Data belongs in storage, not in code. Read the data from a worksheet, you'll get a 2D variant array for free, with a one-liner, without abusing language syntax, and if the data needs to change, then the code doesn't:

```
Dim my2D As Variant
my2D = sourceRange.Value
```

---

<sup>1</sup> unless it's a VBA *foreign identifier*, in which case Excel doesn't get to evaluate it. Just don't use square bracket expressions, they're confusing.